# Using sample library for in-app billing in Android: Interface created by IInAppBillingService.aidl

Tags: android, android-billing

With Google's new in-app billing library (version 3), it should be [significantly easier](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3.html) to add billing to one's applications. The code shown in the developers blog (see link) looks quite simple already.

However, I came across the sample application in the SDK's folder `extras\google\market_billing\in-app-billing-v03`. It's called "TrivialDrive".

When I tried to use the sample code, some questions raised:

1. Is pasting the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into the new package `com.android.vending.billing` correct? The Java interface that is created then shows two to-do messages for me, e.g. in `getBuyIntent()`: "TODO: change this to app-specific keys". Doesn't sound good. Is this interface production-ready, though?
2. There's a folder `util` in the sample's "src", containing `IabHelper`, `Base64`, `Purchase` and other classes. Can I simply copy that directory and use all these helper functions as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confusing the sample code with the generated AIDL stub. The implementation of the in-app billing service is in the Google Play Store client, the AIDL file is just a means to call it (using RPC). You are supposed to change the sample code in order to get it work with your account, key and items. As for the code in `util`, the license is permissive, so you can copy it and use it. You can, of course, build your own library from scratch, by only calling the `IInAppBillingService` using the generated stub.

Comment: Thank you! What I wanted to know is, not regarding the license, if the code in `util` is secure and ready for a production release. And yes, the AIDL file creates a Java interface in the `gen` directory, and there I get some warnings about unused variables _and_ two to-do messages stating that the file needs an update (see the question). This is what made me afraid this is secure and ready for release.

Comment: There are no TODOs in the generated code. This is sample code treat it as such. There are at least a few things missing (checking purchase status for example) and it might not be too robust. So test, modify, improve until it feels right for your app. This is the first release as well, so there might be rough edges at the server side as well. YMMV, of course.

Comment: I missed that one, but yes, first release. In any case, the actual implementation is in the Play Store app, so it might have been updated already.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to know if this is secure. The to-do message sounds as if that AIDL has not been configured to use app-specific keys (as it says) and this would mean: a) security risk - or - b) not working at all.

Comment: Well, it works. At the moment there are no real app specific keys, each app has the same key (check your development console). This might change in the future though. In any case, it shouldn't matter for you (you get a signature and you have to verify it). Not sure what that comment means. You can try opening an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/

Comment: Okay, thank you! I just thought that there _are_ app-specific keys as they explicitly hint at that fact in the documentation. It reads that you find the key in the new developer console in an app's details. But you are right, these keys are all the same.